# Pass a variable that contains a comma as a -v option to qsub

Tags: bash, shell, pbs, qsub, variable-expansion

In qsub, we can pass environment variables like so:

```bash
info="This is some info"
qsub -v INFO=$info script.pbs
```

However, this becomes problematic when $info contains a comma.

```bash
info="This is some info, and here is some more!"
qsub -v INFO=$info script.pbs
```

This will trigger an error like so:

> ERROR: `-v`: variable '  and here is some more!' is not set in environment variables.

I have also tried encapsuling `info`, `INFO="$info"` leading to the same issue.

How can I pass `$info` correctly, even if it contains one or more commas? The same question holds with newlines.

---

Perhaps an interesting observation is that when I `echo -e $info` I get the output that I expect. The error is triggered in the `qsub` command specifically.

Comment: The same way you created the variable: `qsub -v INFO="$info" script.pbs`

Comment: @TimRoberts That yields the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, that's the right way.  It depends on what `qsub` is doing.  If `qsub` is itself a bash script, then you start getting into quoting hell.  You have to start doing hacks like `INFO=\"$info\"` or `INFO="\"$info\""`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not sure what qsub is doing under the hood but I tried both your suggestions and they do not seem to work. So perhaps I shall just do a substitution on the var and replace all commas by semicolons or so.

Comment: please post the output of `file $(type qsub | awk '{print $NF}') ; uname -srv`. Good luck.

Comment: No idea what `qsub` is, but it sounds like it splits the argument to `-v` on comma. Does its documentation say anything about how to escape them in that argument so they're treated literally?

Comment: @shellter `/usr/libexec/jobcli/qsub: Python script, ASCII text executable`. If it helps: I find that the newlines that are passed to the qsub command qre qlso striped (backslashes removed), even though when I echo them from within the script they are presented correctly. Escaping the backslashes of the newline ones does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Shawn pbs is a tool to submit jobs (bash scripts) to a compute cluster. The documentation specifies that indeed `-v` expects a comma-separated list although it is not defined how variables should be escaped. https://www.jlab.org/hpc/PBS/qsub.html

Comment: Do  you get anything for `man qsub`, or `apropos qsub`? Check the documentation would be my next advice (not a `qsub` user). Also, just because you see `\n` in output renderings, doesn't mean there is a real backslash, it is just a convention to display it that way and doubling up the backslash only will confuse things further. Good luck.

Comment: Then it might not be possible to use it to set a variable whose value includes commas.

Comment: Your example is unclear. You don't set (or pass) any environment variable. Essentially, you invoke `qsub -v INFO=This is some info script.pbs`, i.e. casll `qsub` with 6 parameter (`-v`. `INFO=This`, `is`, `some`, `info` and `script.pbs`). AFIK, this causes qsub to set the environment variable `INFO` to _This_ in the child processes it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found on the [qsub man-page](https://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html), that there is no documented way for the option *-v variable[=value],...* to safely place a comma into *value*. Perhaps there is an undocumented way which you can find out by studying the source code of *qsub*.

However there is a workaround: If we just specify `-v variable` without providing a value, it interprets *variable* as environment variable in the current environment, and uses its value. In your case, this means that you can do a

```
export INFO="some string, having commas"
qsub -v INFO script.pbs
```